# При переносе сайта с базы MySQL на SQL Server 2008 перестала работать пагинация

Tags: php, yii

Добрый вечер.
У меня такой вопрос. При переносе сайта с базы `MySQL` на `SQL Server 2008` перестала работать пагинация там где была проставлена реляционная связь. Тоесть пример критерии.:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->with = array('fk_device');
.......... 
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
'criteria'=>$criteria,
));
```

А когда я убираю связь `$criteria->with = array('fk_device');` то навигация по страницам работает.
Можна было бы убрать но потом не будет работать поиск по этой связи `$criteria->with = array('fk_device');`

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос. Может кому то тоже поможет это. Хотя это извращение как по мне, скрещивание Apache + SQL Server 2008 + PHP. Ну все же ответ:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->with = array('fk_device');
.......... 
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
'criteria'=>$criteria,
'sort'=>array(
'defaultOrder' => 't.id ASC',
),
));
```

Вот и все, что надо было сделать. И постраничная навигация работает как надо))).